# Irreducible representations of a non-split group extension by an Abelian group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, semidirect-product, group-extensions

Consider the group extension

$$1\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow K\longrightarrow 1$$
where $A$ is a discrete abelian group and $K$ is a finite group. If the sequence splits, we can write $G$ as a semi-direct product
$$ G=K\ltimes A.$$
In section 8.2 of Serre (Linear representations of finite groups), the irreducible representations of this group is classified. Essentially, given a character $\chi$ of $A$ we have the stabilizer subgroup under $G$ action
$$ A_\chi = K_\chi\ltimes A=\{g\in G |\chi(gag^{-1})=\chi(a), \forall a\in A\},$$
where $K_\chi\subset K$.
Irreducible representations $\chi$ of $A$ and $\sigma$ of $K_\chi$ can both be lifted to $K_\chi\ltimes A$. We then have the following induced representations of $G$
$$ \Gamma_{\chi,\sigma} = \text{Ind}_{K_\chi\ltimes A}^G(\sigma\otimes\chi).$$
Proposition 25 says that all irreducible representations of $G$ are of this form and thus parametrized by $\chi$ and $\sigma$.

My question is, how does the above construction change if $G$ is a non-split extension of $K$ by $A$?

EDIT: Just in case it simplifies things, I am mainly interested in unitary representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely false. For example, the theory of quasisimple groups (groups $G$ such that $G$ is equal to its derived subgroup and $G/Z(G)$ is simple) comes under the theory of groups with an abelian normal subgroup. The theory of such groups is the fundamental block of the study of all characters of finite groups, called Clifford theory. If the extension is split then you can do what is in Serre, but in general you need to consider *projective* representations of the quotient $G$, which are homomorphisms from $G$ to $PGL_n$, not $GL_n$.

The faithful representations of, for example, $SL_n(q)$, which is such a quasisimple group, cannot be deduced from anything to do with $PSL_n(q)$, the quotient by the abelian normal subgroup.

Comment: That is really interesting. I had expected that this would involve projective representations (as I had seen in some physics related context).  Do you know a good reference that discusses these things on the same level of detail as Serre?

Comment: @Heidar Clifford's original paper is very readable. BUt once you try to analyse the theory more, it gets incredibly complicated. Isaacs's book on character theory might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, I will take a look at these.